# cakephp - using create() not working as expected

Tags: cakephp

I have a product controller and when I'm saving a new product I want to save some records to another related controller to make a record of what categories the product is associated with.

My code I'm using is:

```
$this->Product->create();
if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) {
    $newProductId = $this->Product->getInsertID();
    //associate products with categories
    foreach($categoriesToSave as $key=>$value) {
        $saveArray['CategoriesProduct'] = array('category_id'=>$value, 'product_id'=>$newProductId);
        $this->Product->CategoriesProduct->create();
        $this->Product->CategoriesProduct->save($saveArray);
        $this->Product->CategoriesProduct->clear();
    }
}
```

For some reason though, even if `$categoriesToSave` has 10 items in it, only the very last one is being saved. So it's obviuosly creating only the one new CategoriesProduct item and saving each record over the top of the last instead of `create()`-ing a new one.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can make this work?

Comment: Do you have a `unique` constraint on the `CategoriesProduct` model? Or some specific definition? And what's the relationship between `Product` and `CategoriesProduct`?

Comment: Are you in a debug environment? If not, I always check the logs when there is something going on that isn't clear. They are located here: app\tmp\logs

Comment: omg... I'm a dopey idiot. I'd left out the primary key for the categories_products table - thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: The best of us have those moments! Sometimes with Cakephp I assumed the issue is with Cakephp itself, but it's some weird constraint in the DB that is causing the issue. That's why I check the logs. @Holt was right to point you in that direction.

Comment: When you encounter issue with model queries, the first thing to do is to check the queries generated by CakePHP, by using either `$this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false)` in your controller or `$this->element('sql_dump')`. Once you have the queries, put them directly in the DB, if the problem is still there, the issue does not come from Cake.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be like this:

```
//Add a counter
$c = 0
foreach($categoriesToSave as $key=>$value) {
    $saveArray[$c]['CategoriesProduct']['category_id'] = $value;
    $saveArray[$c]['CategoriesProduct']['product_id']  = $newProductId;
    $c++;
}
$this->Product->CategoriesProduct->saveMany($saveArray);
```

I don't think that is the only way to do it but that should work just fine.

Good luck!